# How to collapse a Bootstrap column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

How can I collapse my sidebar in between 2 sections like in the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example actually works outside of the js fiddle environment. The problem is the `@media` query doesn't take effect in this environment so the float messes up.

http://jsfiddle.net/v38q68h2/12/

```
<div class="col-md-8" id="a">
    A
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 pull-right" id="b">
   B
</div>
<div class="col-md-8" id="c">
    C
</div>

#a{
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
}
#b{
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
#c{
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You could definitely make some optimizations, but just having the sidebar wrapper come before the bottom section seems to have it fall into place correctly. The only real downside is that you'd have to build your sidebar into the main content.

Comment: Your answer helped me alot. Thanks! Appreciate your time.

Comment: +1 because of the answer but mostly because of your user name.